# Azure Search: geo.intersects returning incorrect results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using the following query for Azure Search:

$filter=geo.intersects(coordinate, geography'POLYGON((1.136 44.733, 1.316 44.733, 1.316 44.553, 1.136 44.553, 1.136 44.733))')

This should return all points inside this polygon, which is a small area in south-western France. Unfortunately Azure Search returns results from outside the polygon.

Examples of results that seem incorrect to me (corrected, see comments):

- lon=5.299151, lat=44.695285,
- lon=0.397723, lat=44.668628,

The points in the polygon are entered clockwise (which was mentioned in a related question), but still results are incorrect.

Any suggestions on fixing the query?

I'm using the following code for feeding the index:

public class Geometry

```
{
    public Geometry(Coordinate c)
    {
        List<double> GeoList = new List<double>();         
        GeoList.Add((double)c.Longitude);
        GeoList.Add((double)c.Latitude);
        type = "Point";
        coordinates = GeoList;
    }

    public string type { get; set; }
    public IList<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In your example of co-ordinates that seem incorrect, it looks like lon and lat are swapped. Was this a typo, or are those the actual results you're seeing?

Comment: they are returned in lat-lon order (I've edited the question to reflect the correct order):

"coordinate": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.299151,
                    44.695285
                ],
                "crs": {
                    "type": "name",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "EPSG:4326"
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: To correct my previous comment, as I can't edit that comment any more: they are indeed wrong, I mixed them up. That must be the explanation. I'll test and let you know the result.

Comment: Your $filter query looks fine to me. It may be the co-ordinates in your index that are backwards.

Comment: thanks, I'll check the indexing code

Comment: I've compared the json returned in azjobsdemo.azurewebsites.net with the json from my own SearchService. The json returned in the AZjobsdemo is indeed different: "geo_location": {
    "Latitude": 40.710105,
    "Longitude": -74.003242,
    "IsEmpty": false,
    "Z": null,
    "M": null,
    "CoordinateSystem": {
     "EpsgId": 4326,
     "Id": "4326",
     "Name": "WGS84"
    }
   }

Comment: Error is most probably in the class I wrote for creating a GEOjson object. I'll keep this thread updated if it works.

Comment: Are you using the .NET SDK? If so, you can use the Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint class instead of rolling your own. SDK is here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search

Comment: BTW: after simply switching latitude and longitude in the above Geometry class (and reindexing) I didn't get any results any more (neither correct nor incorrect results). To be continued.

Comment: I am using the .NET SDK. I'll try to use that class, thanks

Comment: I've replaced my own class by the Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint class and reindexed. No change in the results unfortunately.

Comment: There's nothing obvious left to check... Please email me at bruce.johnston at the usual domain and we can troubleshoot more in-depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Put points in counterclockwise order when defining a polygon.

---

A more nuanced answer is:

Azure Search uses OData which uses the [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format to define geometric objects. As [per the WKT spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) polygon points are in counterclockwise order if you want to include the area inside the polygon as seen from the top. This gets tricky to think about since we are dealing with non euclidean geometry.

> The [polygon] defines the “top” of the surface which is the side of the surface from which the exterior boundary appears to traverse the boundary in a counter clockwise direction.

To solve your issue try putting your points in counter-clockwise order instead

```
$filter=geo.intersects(coordinate,geography'POLYGON((1.136 44.733, 1.136 44.553, 1.316 44.553, 1.316 44.733, 1.136 44.733))')
```